# problem with saving to esri file

Tags: qgis, vector, export, error, dbf

I was using Wroclaw 1.7/GDAL 1.9(earlier release)/Grass 6.4/GSL 1.15-2 and started getting the following message when saving any item to esri format.

"Export to vector file failed.
Error: creation of layer failed (OGR error:Failed to open Shape DBF file `/Users/jes....dbf)"
And when I look for the file/sibling files, the dbf is not there.

I just updated everything QGIS 1.8/GDAL 1.9 (December, 3 2012)/Grass 6.4.2. Still getting the same message with any feature that I save.

What can I do to fix this asap?

Comment: Its almost definitely got something to do with writting permissions i'd say. Thats why your file isn't there and creation fails

Comment: Save it to somewhere else, the default is inside QGis installation directory and Windows will not allow this.

Comment: I've tried saving to different location. Same issue.

Comment: Check security settings on the different location. Also, have you tried running the program "As Administrator"

Comment: does your original shapefile have dbf,shx and shp files in its folder?

Comment: Had the same problem in version 2.2.0. A.R.s suggestion works for me.